# What is the name for this function associated with Distribution Function?

Tags: probability-distributions, terminology, descriptive-statistics

Suppose a country where the distribution of income $Y$ is given by a *Probability Density Function* (PDF) that we call $f_Y(y)$, obviously:

$$\int_0^\infty f_Y(y)\ \text{d}y = 1$$

The expected proportion of accumulated income $p_{acc}(y)$ by people with income below $y$ is given by:

$$0 \le p_{acc}(y) = \frac{\int_0^y y' f_Y(y')\ \text{d}y'}{\int_0^{\infty} y'f_Y(y')\ \text{d}y'} \le 1$$

I am almost sure that in the general case, outside of income distribution problems, this type function $p_{acc}(y)$ has a generic name, but I can't figure out which one. That is, given any PDF $f_Y$, I don't know if anyone knows what this computable magnitude is called for any type of PDF.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Lorenz curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve), whose integral is the [Gini coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient).